# How to ensure AWS EC2 application is private and nonaccessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an application hosted on AWS EC2 that will be called via a cron schedule and is not to be publicly accessible.  It is only to be called by the cron schedule file and nothing and no one else.  How do I ensure the application remains private?

Right now it has a public IP address to connect to which is accessible via SSH only from my ip address.  Is that sufficient security in addition to correct file permissions?  What would those file permissions be?

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that you have a couple of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. If all of them were not good, then that's fine. But if they were helpful, acceptance is not only a good practice, but it also removes your question for [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services?tab=Unanswered) list.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it has a public IP address to connect to which is accessible via SSH only from my ip address.

Depends how strict are your security requirements. For maximum privacy, you would create a **private VPC** without any public subnets. So your EC2 instance would be in a private subnet without any inbound nor outbound access to the internet.

For such an instance, you wouldn't use ssh. Instead you could use [SSM Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to access it with strict IAM permissions regarding who can access the instance.

Comment: Does the private VPC have substantially better security than SSH with specific-ip only?  Any tips on setting up the private VPC?

Comment: @r04jj Yes, it is better because you are eliminating any internet access to it. With ssh, anyone who has your private key can access the instance. With SSM manager, you use IAM user/role permissions for that and you have full log of who and when was using SSM. The setup is more complex then when vpc has public subnets. But, the question is, do you really need such level of security? Maybe ssh with specific-ip is enough for your use-case? Only you can know that.

Comment: @r04jj How did it go?